# How to update Activity's variable during AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to update a variable from AsyncTask, but I'm not exactly sure how. This is what I tried:

Outside the AsyncTask is the activity class that has a variable..:

> ```
> int myVariable = 0;
> MyTask hi = new MyTask ();
> hi.execute();
> System.out.print(myVariable);
> ```

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... args0) {
                    myVariable = 3;
            return null;

        }
    }
```

Still prints out 0 :(

When i print out the variable, it still says 0, and not 3. I'm using AsynTask for something more complicated, but this is the dumbed down version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Where are you printing your variable?

Comment: In the activity class that holds the AsyncTask

Comment: @Phil, i just updated it.

Comment: Please see my answer for detail :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print your variable inside the **doInBackground() or the onProgressUpdate()** method. Since the doInBackground() method does not run on the UI-Thread it is highly likely that **the print-statement gets executed before the variable is incremented.**

Like this: (assuming that "myVariable" is of type Integer, and this AsyncTask is an inner class of your Activity)

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args0) {

          for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

              myVariable++;
              // like this:
              Log.i("Variable", "" + myVariable);
              // or like this:
              publishProgress(myVariable);
          }

          return null;
    }

    protected Void onProgressUpdate(Integer... prog) {
          Log.i("Variable", "" + prog[0]);
    }
}
```

Plese be aware that **the for-loop I am using is just an example**, you could do anything there and then update your variable and publish it. Also be aware that I changed the "Progress" type to Integer:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helps! I never knew the background thread was finishing last until you told me this!

Answer (score 0):

The **AsyncTask** main three methods are **onPreExecute, doInBackground, onPostExecute**.

The method **onPreExecute** of *AsyncTask*  is mainly used for *showing a **loading/processing dialog** so that until the process is completed the user interaction with the **UI is disabled***.

The method **doInBackground** of *AsyncTask*  is mainly used for *doing the **background calculations** or calling a **web service***.

The method **onPostExecute** of *AsyncTask*  is mainly used for *showing the **output of the doInBackground** method and it can be used for **performing actions on the UI***.

***@CynthiaDDurazo:***  So, in your case you should ***use onPostExecute*** method to put your code ***System.out.println(myVariable);***